# Which measure is this?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\nu$ a probability measure on a space $\Omega$. Suppose that for every function $f\in C(\Omega)$ such that $\int_\Omega f(x)dx=0$ it holds that

$$\int_\Omega f(x)d\nu=0$$.

I would like to prove that the probability measure $\nu(dx)=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}dx$. Is this true? How could I prove this? For sure I need to use that  $\nu$ is a probability measure and therefore is always positive. But I don't know how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym decomposition?

Comment: What is $\Omega$? If you're talking about $f\in C(\Omega)$, it must be more than just any measure space.

Comment: @JustDroppedln Not really but I will give a look. Thank you!

Comment: @Thrgott $\Omega$ is a bounded subspace of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Do you mean the Theorem that claims that for every signed measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\Omega$, there exist unique two measures $\nu_0$ (absolutely cotinuous respect to $\mu$) and $\nu_1$ (singular respect to $\mu$) such that $\nu=\nu_0+\nu_1$?

Comment: I don't see very well how to apply such decomposition to my problem.

Comment: I could conclude from that theorem if I knew that $\nu<<\frac{1}{|\Omega|}dx$. But can I say that $\nu<<\frac{1}{|\Omega|}dx$?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $\Omega$ is  a compact subset of $\mathbb R$. By Riesz Representation Theorem the  dual of $C(\Omega)$ consists of regular Borel measures on $\Omega$. The measures $\nu$ and $dx$ define two linear functionals $F$ and $G$ on this space. It is given that $G(f)=0$ implies $F(f)=0$. An  elementary linear algebra result shows that $G$ is a multiple of $F$. This gives $\int f d\nu =\int f \frac  1 {|\Omega|} dx$ for every continuous  function $f$ and this implies $\frac  1 {\Omega} dx=\nu$.

EDIT:
This does not require Riesz Representation Theorem. We only have to observe that $F$ and $G$ are linear functionals on $C(\Omega)$ such that $ker (F) \subseteq ker (G)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but there are some things that are not clear to me: 1) How the functionals $F$ and $G$ are defined. Is $G(f)=\int_{\Omega}f(x)dx$ and $F(f)=\int_{\Omega}f(x)d\nu$?

Comment: 2) Which is the algebric result that allows me to conclude that if $G(\bar f)=0$ implies $F(\bar f)=0$ then $F(f)=kG(f)$?

Comment: I think I found the answer to my second question. I have a third question. 3) In your argument where do I use the Riesz Representation Theorem?

Comment: @user268193 Nowhere! I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I ask you a book reference about the result that if $G$ and $F$ are two linear functionals such that $ker(F)\subseteq Ker(G)$ then $G=kF$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Take $f_0$ such that $F(f_0) \neq 0$. For any $f$ let $c=\frac {F(f)} {F(f_0)}$ and observe that $F-cf_0 \in ker (F) \subset ker (G)$. Hence $G(f-cf_0)=-0$. This proves that $G(f)=aF(f)$ for all $f$ where $a=\frac {G(f_0)} {F(f_0)}$.